# MLE for the Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution

I understand how a random sample $x_1, ..., x_n$ following the Uniform Distribution with $0 \leq x \leq \theta$ has a log-likelihood proportional to $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$. I am told that the MLE for $\theta$, or $\hat\theta$ to be exact, is then equal to the MAXIMUM of $x_i$. This doesn't make sense to me, because the larger $x$ is, the smaller $\frac{1}{\theta^2}$ is, so to me it seems like the MLE for $\theta$ would be the MINIMUM of $x_i$. But apparently this is incorrect. Someone explain why, please?

Comment: Please check your initial understanding.  Bear in mind that the likelihood is *zero* for all $x\lt 0$ and all $x \gt \theta.$ Review the rules of working with logarithms.  Search our site for [uniform self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniform+%5Bself-study%5D+is%3Aquestion+) for many, many solutions to this and essentially similar problems.

Comment: Done. Didn't answer my question.

Comment: Please stop re-asking the same question. Edit the question here to explain what you find unsatisfactory about the answers to the duplicate (both of which explicitly point out that the likelihood of $\theta$ below the sample maximum is zero). This is to your own benefit, as you've no reason to expect substantively different answers unless you do so.

Comment: My comment directly answered your stated question: you err in the calculation of the log likelihood and that explains why what you have done doesn't make sense.  But the more useful and relevant information is contained in the duplicate.

Comment: @Dan W: Sorry - your 3rd posting is substantially different & does explain the problem you still have with the answers to the duplicate. I shouldn't have deleted it, & have now undeleted it. (It would still have been better, though, to edit this one.)